# Manipular fechas de Python en español

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

La librería `datetime` de Python ofrece la facilidad de transformar las primeras 3 palabras de una fecha a números.

```
fecha_dt = datetime.strptime("01-aug-2019", '%d-%b-%Y')
```

Me gustaría poder hacer lo mismo pero en español utilizando el siguiente código.

```
fecha_dt = datetime.strptime("01-ago-2019", '%d-%b-%Y')
```

¿Existe alguna librería o manera de realizar el código expuesto?

Comment: Mmm se me hace dificil pensar que una libreria esté en español honestamente, principalmente porque la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/datetime.html) en español tambien te lo explica en ingles

Comment: Lastimosamente nos queda adaptarnos al estándar inglés, lo que puedes hacer es un diccionario con las palabras en español y así hacer una traducción sencilla

Comment: Entiendo muchas gracias, solo me quería evitar el trabajo de generar condiciones para cambiar el nombre.

Answer (score 1):

Aunque lo mejor sea trabajar con las fechas en inglés igual te es de utilidad la siguiente respuesta de stackoverlow en inglés: [Converting spanish date into python pandas datetime object with locale setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54849263/12771230)
 que lo soluciona usando [locale](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html).

`locale` es un set de variables de entorno que define el formato de fecha y hora, el lenguaje, los encoding, el formato numérico, -entre otras cosas- del sistema.

Si estás con Linux puedes obtener el valor de todas las variables con el comando `locale`:

```
$ -> locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_TIME=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_NAME=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Tienes el significado de cada una de ellas en el siguiente enlace: [Understanding locale environment variables](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=locales-understanding-locale-environment-variables)
.

- Código de la otra respuesta:

```
# Importa el módulo:
import locale
# Setea la variable LC_ALL al conjunto de código UTF-8 con descripción español España
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'es_ES.UTF-8')

from datetime import datetime as dt

time_example = dt.strptime('01-ago-2019', '%d-%b-%Y')

# Setea la variable LC_ALL al encode UTF-8 y los formatos Inglés, Estados Unidos
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'en_US.UTF-8')

print(time_example)
print(time_example.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

- Resultado:

```
$ -> python3 spanish_date.py 
2019-08-01 00:00:00
2019-08-01
```